# Keeping composer.json updated and maintained

Tags: symfony, version-control, dependencies, version, composer-php

Here's a topic that seems a bit hard to find information on.  Do I need to update / future-proof the `composer.json` file that comes with Symfony as the ~approximate versions stray farther and farther away from the actual latest versions?

Is this just left to an etiquette or preference thing?  I hope not, because as a developer its hard enough to maintain standards. I would like to see some concrete rules in the `composer.json` `require` regarding the way versions are read and indicated.

e.g. what do I do when my composer.json says

```
"require": {
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
```

but downloads Doctrine 7.4 and Symfony 4.3 instead?  Is this okay?  Or do I need need to maintain my composer.json file?

Composer.lock is for this you say?  What is composer.lock? It's a file I don't need to adjust, not interested in looking at, and don't want to edit.  Thats the conclusion i hold on composer.lock.

Compatible with symfony? Entries like this drive me a bit batty, `"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",`  @dev?  I would love to see that gone. And how do I know which packages are which, i.e. how do I know if I need a name like "2.0.*@dev"`(which has the version, and a phase tag (dev)), or`"dev-master"`(which states no version number, I think I like this one the best, but then you will have complicated version mismatch issues, so this might not be a good standard at all), there is no standards there.

(Mind you, I don't need an explanation as to why the package is only available as @dev, I realize its not a completed work yet.  This isn't my point).

Back to keeping the composer.json file itself updated, does it really boil down having to Googling every one of these packages, every couple months, looking over at package gist, npm, and git hub repo documentations, just to find that elusive version number, guess at it to take the risk that you're looking at the right website, latest code release, then update your composer.json file with that number, after you verify it is compatible with all other packages?  I mean, isn't that what a package manager is supposed to do for me?

The best documentation I have seen for version compat info is the chart here http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/getting-started.html#requirements.  It would be great if all current mainstream open source packages can adopt this compatibility chart idea like this, at least if they are able to be installed by composer.json who does have an implemented version check system within.

So shouldn't my attention be to composer.json periodically to make sure it contains the correct version numbers?  I mean, its easy to ignore, but I think this will be fatal, and not ignoring it is why I have just created this post. What is the correct way to go about maintaining the composer.json, and what few resources are available for this?

Anyway can't I find a default composer.json file anywhere?  It would be great to see one for each new Symfony release so I can just update the top default Symfony requires easily at least X.

### Further related questions

PHP, true, I was entirely overlooking the PHP one, thanks for pointing that out. So that states the compatible version. Notice, I removed the PHP portion of the question and revised it to an example using Doctrine and Symfony instead.

As far as declaring ~2.4 will not install anything over 2.x, I think is what you're saying, this is what I had hoped to hear. This is great to know for sure!

The test suite, again, something I haven't used in the Symfony package. Thus far i have been relying on web drivers.

Ahh, `--prefer-lowest?` What does this verify, that the versions that I do have specified are at least compatible with each other?

So on your next point, you mention below the compat chart comment, about if it's a dependency it belongs in required section, if it's not dependency it should not be placed in `required`, rather just add the files directly to `app/resources`?

You ask what purpose would it have to have a default composer.json file. If I had one to refer to, I would know that the edits that have slowly made their way to my configs over the last two years haven't completely caused the breakage that I'm experiencing right now. I just want to see some solid ground, and possible even revert my file back, delete vendors, and web, and composer install/update to see if things start working again, then add one package back at a time. I can't do this right now, because I have no way to reference what I have against what works.

Are you saying I can generate a fresh with composer init? I totally forgot about this. Great point.

Another point you made below the `composer init` about semantic versioning major version increment.  I didn't realize that this was a standard practice to jump to the next number block when something goes out of compat. I don't know why I hadn't correlated that in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one central, very wrong sentence:

> e.g. what do i do when my composer.json says "require": {
>           "php": ">=5.3.3",
>           "symfony/symfony": "~2.4", but downloads php 7.4 and symfony 4.3 instead? is this ok? Or do i ineed need to maintain my composer.json file?

Wrong, Composer will not install any version of PHP, but will warn you if the version used is incompatible with what is declared. It will not install packages that will not run with your installed version of PHP.

And wrong, when declaring "~2.4", this means to not install version 3.0 and above, so this won't install symfony 4.3 ever.

But yes, you need to maintain your composer.json. You should check at least two things periodically, maybe three:

1. Does your software run with the latest allowed packages? E.g. run `composer update`, then your test suite - it should work.
2. Does your software run with the lowest required versions? E.g. run `composer update --prefer-lowest`, then your test suite - it should work.
3. Does your software run with an arbitrary combination of package versions - for example with the combination recorded in the composer.lock file?

If you find any incompatibilities, you should probably try to exclude these versions.

I, too, would love to see dependencies on branches to be a thing of the past. Depending on a dev version of a release is only slightly less bad. But as long as the most common installation instruction tells the user to "require dev-master", this won't happen soon. The community still needs a good bit of education on why using branches is a bad thing.

I don't think the compatibility chart you mentioned adds anything useful. There is no such thing as an optional dependency. If it is needed, it belongs into the "required" section. If it's not needed, it is no dependency. If another package can be used together with this one, and putting them together is the task of the main application - that's a task for the application developer to manage.

> Any why cant i find a default composer.json file anywhere? it would be great to see one for each new symfony release so i can just update the top default symfony requires easily atleast...

What purpose would that have? The default composer.json probably will be created by running `composer init` and answering the questions, i.e. adding a name, a description, a license, a developer contact and - optionally - some dependencies. The whole point of semantic versioning is that incompatible updates are clearly marked as a major version increment, allowing you to not install them when updating. If you say that you can use Symfony version 2.3, you should expect Symfony version 2.99 to also run your application.

The problem is feature creep - you might accidentially use a compatible feature of e.g. Symfony 2.5, which would be missed in 2.3 and violate your minimum version requirement. Thats what `--prefer-lowest` is for in your automated tests: You should investigate if the test fails, and update your version requirements if the failure is due to lack of features in the minimum version requirement - or fix the code that incorrectly used a feature that wasn't present in the minimum required version if that's the goal.

Comment: Sven, thanks a bunch, you nailed it!  My reply is too long, please see it in the OP, then bounce back here with your comments if you have any.  thanks.